# Changing the Location of a dynamically created custom control

Tags: c#, winforms

Let’s say we have the following class `Cell`, which is composed of a `Label` control:

```
class Cell : UserControl
{
    Label base;

    public Cell(Form form)
    {
        base = new Label();
        base.Parent = form;        
        base.Height = 30;
        base.Width = 30;
    }
} 

public partial class Form1 : Form
{ 
    Label label = new Label();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Cell cell = new Cell(this);
        cell.Location = new Point(150, 150);   //this doesnt work            
        label.Location = new Point(150,150);   //but this does
    }
}
```

A single `Cell` will display in the `Form`, but anchored to the `top left (0,0)` position.

Setting the Location property to a new `Point` with any other coordinates does nothing, as the `Cell` will remain in the upper left.

However, if one were to create a new `Label` and then attempt to set its location, the label would be moved.

Is there a way to do this on my `Cell` object?

Comment: Do you add the control to the Controls collection? Do you use docking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your main problem is that you are not adding the controls to a container correctly.

First, you need to add the inner Label to the Cell;

```
class Cell : UserControl
{       
    Label lbl;

    public Cell()
    {
        lbl = new Label();
        lbl.Parent = form;        
        lbl.Height = 30;
        lbl.Width = 30;
        this.Controls.Add(lbl); // label is now contained by 'Cell'
    }
}
```

Then, you need to add the Cell to the Form;

```
Cell cell = new Cell();
form.Controls.Add(cell);
```

Also; 'base' is a reserved word, so you can't name the inner label control such.

Comment: Thank you, this works! Could you also help me to display a series of these cells within a form? Such that a 300 x 300 form area could be filled with 30 x 30 cells to make a grid? I can create and display multiple cells now, but it's almost as if each one has a large area of blank space around it that obscures the others.

Comment: EDIT: just figured out how to do this. It's simply a matter of bringing each new Cell object to the front using Cell.BringToFront()

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
class Cell : Label
    {

    public Cell(Form form)
        {

                this.Parent = form;        
            this.Height = 30;
            this.Width = 30;
        }
    } 


    public partial class Form1 : Form
    { 
        Label label = new Label();


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            Cell cell = new Cell(this);

            cell.Location = new Point(150, 150);   //this doesnt work

            label.Location = new Point(150,150);   //but this does

        }
```

Comment: But it doesn't do the same thing. It exposes all the label functionality and you can't add more controls to the user control.